# Google OAuth Consent Screen Shows Different Information In Development Versus Production

Tags: google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I noticed that the Google OAuth consent screen shows different information in development versus production.

## Development Google OAuth Consent Screen

[image]
The path for the development environment before we are redirected to the Google OAuth Consent Screen is as follows:
**http://localhost/tips-and-trips-by-sham/google_calendar_add_event/**

The path for the development environment for the Google OAuth Consent Screen is as follows:
**https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/oauthchooseaccount?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fgoogle_calendar_add_event_php%2Fgoogle_calendar_event_sync.php&response_type=code&client_id=179430523214-h7u06vpoj31hec4vpbn2sust7c8ltkee.apps.googleusercontent.com&access_type=offline&service=lso&o2v=1&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow**

## Production Google OAuth Consent Screen

[image]
The path for the production environment before we are redirected to the Google OAuth Consent Screen is as follows:
**https://shaynhacker.com/clients/travel/travel/google_calendar_add_event/**

The path for the production environment for the Google OAuth Consent Screen is as follows:
**https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/oauthchooseaccount?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fshaynhacker.com%2Fclients%2Ftravel%2Ftravel%2Fgoogle_calendar_add_event%2Fgoogle_calendar_event_sync.php&response_type=code&client_id=179430523214-h7u06vpoj31hec4vpbn2sust7c8ltkee.apps.googleusercontent.com&access_type=offline&service=lso&o2v=1&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow**

Now, the information shown on the Google OAuth Consent Screen in the development environment is what I want to be shown in the production environment which is **Trips & Tips By Sham** and not my email address.

I followed the instructions on the relevant Google page https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent?project=rich-store-372122 but to no avail.
The instructions here did not meet my needs because it's showing my personal email address instead of the title I gave on that page which is **Trips & Tips By Sham** in the production environment.

## Consent Screen Configuration/Consent Screen Details

[image]

Comment: Can I seen the consent screen configuration for the two projects?

Comment: Did you make sure that the consent screen name has the name of the application "Trips & Tips By Sham"? It would be great if you can share the information shown in the consent screen details page.

Comment: @GabrielCarballo  I have updated the question and provided the consent screen configuration/consent screen details.

Comment: @DaImTo  I have updated the question and provided the consent screen configuration/consent screen details.

Comment: Is there an approval process required for your app? A guy with a similar issue mentioned that getting his app approved solved the issue https://groups.google.com/g/google-cloud-dev/c/kRpnA6Jnz0A

Comment: Could you share the image of what is shown in the consent screen when you try to use the app?

Comment: @GabrielCarballo The image(s) was already shown or attached in the question/post. There is one image for the localhost/development environment and another image for the remote server/production environment.

Answer (score 1):

After checking the documentation related to the `Consent screen` it seems that the display name and logo for a `in production` app are subject to the verification status of your application as shown here:

[image]

Since the problem with your application seems to be with the one `in production` I would suggest checking if your app needs to complete verification, if so, you can perform verification of the app following this [documentation](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914), once again the behavior seems to be expected according to this information:

[image]